# Rundeck: see what is actually executed on the commandline

Tags: rundeck

I'm just getting started with rundeck and trying to find out how it works.

I created a simple Job that should install some packages on the remote note from a pre-selected list (`Option`).

When I select more than one `option` the command fails. I want to find out why it fails but (even with debug-mode enabled) see nowhere which command is actally being executed on the remote node.

My command looks like `yum install -y "${option.package}"` and the unexpected response is eg: `no package [selected options] available` ... I have selected   (space) as delimitter.

How can I see what is executed on the remote host?

Update:

I meanwhile found out why my options did not work as expected; I had to use the *unqouted* variant for the command-line. But the main question still stays the same ...

Comment: @MegaDrive68k that is a good hint for debugging in future :+1: but the main question still is if there is any possibility to see _what actually_ is executed. Seems to be too trivial perhaps.

Comment: I left an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Right now the only way to see the exact executed command is to run the job on debug mode. Just select "[Run with Debug output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxzJ2.jpg)" and you can [see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBcPW.jpg) the command dispatched in the middle of the execution output.

Comment: Yeah, but the question was `where do I see the command beeing executed` aka the commandline rendered from the template. But Thank you anyway.

Comment: Now I understand your question, my bad. Updating my Answer.

Comment: Done. That's the only way to see the command dispatched in your node. Of course, the job should be configured to be executed against the remote node.